# How to read the excess (non-burned) tip fee for a transaction after EIP-1559?

Tags: solidity, fees

I'm trying to understand the programming capabilities of Solidity with the new model of base fee and tip. Pls correct me if I'm wrong, from my understanding, the base fee is setup by the network based on the average last block fees and it is burned when the block is mined. The tip fee, which is what miners will keep, is an extra amount paid to get priority on transactions. My question is:

In solidity I can read tx.gasprice to check how much was the gas price the sender has set for the transaction, if I subtract block.basefee, will it give me the exact amount of the tip fee?